# MAS 90 PHP integeration

Tags: php

I have a web application running in PHP and MySQL. We also uses a Mas 90 ERP solution for our internal purposes. I want to update my MAS 90 database from my web application if any purchase happens from my website. Is possible to update my MAS 90 ERP from my PHP website?

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet might be to use [Sage Web Services for MAS90.](http://www.4ebm.com/mas90/eBusinessManager/Alternatives/)